# Invoke callable Firebase Cloud function in expo

Tags: google-cloud-functions, expo

I tried using approach given on this website: https://rnfirebase.io/

But it states that it doesn't work with EXPO GO app. Is there a way to call firebase callable function while using expo go app?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve it by calling an endpoint as per [document](https://rnfirebase.io/functions/usage#calling-an-endpoint). Assuming you have deployed a callable endpoint named `listProducts`, to call the endpoint the library exposes a `httpsCallable` method.

For example:

```js
// Deployed HTTPS callable
exports.listProducts = functions.https.onCall(() => {
  return [
    /* ... */
    // Return some data
  ];
});
```

Within the React Native application, the list of products returned can be directly accessed:

```js
import functions from '@react-native-firebase/functions';

function App() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    functions()
      .httpsCallable('listProducts')()
      .then(response => {
        setProducts(response.data);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);

  if (loading) {
    return null;
  }

  // ...
}
```